# No identifier specified exception for overridden ID in child class

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have baseEntity class.the id property in this class dose not set @Id and @GeneratedValue annotation

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    private T id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "createdby", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "updatedby")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String updatedBy;

    public BaseEntity(T id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Blog entity set @Id and @GeneratedValue

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "core_blog")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Blog extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "subject", nullable = false)
    private String subject;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

}
```

but i get this exception

```
`No identifier specified for entity: org.roshan.framework.domain.blog.Blog`
```

I dont know what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported `javax.persistence.Id` class.